# Using oreintdb in production with jdbc

Tags: orientdb

I am planning to use orientdb in production using the jdbc drive so i need confirm some points

1. is jdbc driver can give all the orientdb Features like (transaction and  links ...etc) or using the the java api is the best choice
2. I noticed that you have spring data implementation in the orientdb github is it ready to use in the production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/qGPJFQcahjo) a discussion on the issue that you wrote.

in general, JDBC driver supports only a subset of OrientDB, only the part you can use with commands.

If you're a Java developer, I suggest you to use the Java Graph API: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html